# RowLayout in SWT that vertically aligns on the font baseline

Tags: java, fonts, swt

SWT's RowLayout is fine for the purpose, however I'd like the vertical alignment on the font baseline for all widgets containing text.

Is there maybe a ready custom Layout that does this?

[Snippet204.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet204.java) probably has what it takes to implement it, but I just want to ask if it has been done before. Couldn't find it, but it seems like a typical requirement.

In the screenshot's top, there's the row layout, below is a fixed layout that I manually arranged to the baseline (WindowBuilder has snapping for that).

[image: demo screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RowLayout` has a field called [`center`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/RowLayout.html#center). Just set it to `true` and you're good.

> `center` specifies whether the controls in a row should be centered vertically in each cell for horizontal layouts, or centered horizontally in each cell for vertical layouts. The default value is `false`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
    layout.center = true;

    shell.setLayout(layout);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Label");
    new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not pixel-perfect (on Mac OS), but it's close, so I'll leave it like that for now.

Comment: @Phantrast Great! If you can find a better solution, please post it here. If not, please consider accepting my answer.